# Angular 4 get input value from textbox on Japanese input

Tags: angular, input, cjk

I'm using input event called when have any key input in textbox.
but it's work for romanji keyboard,
when I use Japanese input then It does not detect the first letter event I input then press Enter. 
When I enter the second letter (in Japanese) it's got both letter.
Sorry it so difficult to description.
Just imaging when i input あ, it can not detected, 
but I try to input one more letter あ, it detected 2 letter.
I have tried the (input), (change) event but the same result 
please help me.
Thank you.

this is HTML code

```
<input [(ngModel)]="strAutoSearch" class="p-search__text-area" type="text" name="word" (input)="searchAuto(strAutoSearch)">
```

this is .ts file function

```
strAutoSearch: string;
searchAuto(searchValue: string) {
    if (this.strAutoSearch == null || this.strAutoSearch.trim() == "") {
      this.strAutoSearch = "";
      this.result= [];
      return;
    }
    this.listService.searchService(this.strAutoSearch.trim())
      .subscribe(
        result => {
          this.result= result;
        },
        e => this.helpers.handleErrors(e.error)
      );
  }
```

Comment: Are you using the `(keyup)` event on the input field?

Comment: yub, I have tried input, change, keyup, keypress, keydown but same result @AnuradhaGunasekara

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried with HostListener. That should catch all keyboard events.

```
import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
    handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
            console.log(event.keyCode) ; 
    }
```

Comment: I tried, but its nothing change, the same result :(

Comment: @Katsumoto what you get with `console.log(event.keyCode)`?

Comment: I got the character if I input the character, number if I press the function key. It do not detected but the first character in Japanese. just detected both when I try input the second

Comment: @Katsumoto so, when you press first key it doesn't show it is pressed?

Comment: @Katsumoto can you edit your question and paste your source code so I can see what you are doing?

Comment: @Katsumoto instead of `(input)="searchAuto(strAutoSearch)"` try this one: `(keyup)="searchAuto($event)"` and then in your function instead of `searchAuto(searchValue: string) {` write this: `searchAuto(event: KeyboardEvent) {` . Inside your function put this: `console.log((<HTMLInputElement>event.target).value)` Now try to press keys and see what is in console. Let me know if this works.